# How do I Solve this ValueError message that is messing up with my code?

Tags: python, json, plotly

How do I fix the bug in this code? I tried using Try/Except but it did not work.
It blows up on this line of code 'size': [5*mag for mag in mags],
This is the error that I am encountering.. Someone please point me in the direction to fix it.

```
ValueError:
Invalid element(s) received for the 'size' property of scattergeo.marker
    Invalid elements include: [-0.35000000000000003, -1.0, -0.8500000000000001, -0.1, -2.5, 
-0.05, -2.8000000000000003, -2.75, -3.35, -0.4]
```

```
import json
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline


# Get a JSON file.
filename = 'earthquake_data/seven_days_earthquake.json'
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    eq_data = json.load(f)

# Create a readable file from the loaded json file above.

readable_file = 'earthquake_data/readable_eq_data.json'
with open(readable_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(eq_data, f, indent=4)

# Exploring the structure of the data.
title = eq_data["metadata"]["title"]
all_eq_dicts = eq_data["features"]

mags, lons, lats, hover_texts = [], [], [], []
for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts:
    try:
        mags.append(eq_dict["properties"]["mag"])
        lons.append(eq_dict["geometry"]["coordinates"][0])
        lats.append(eq_dict["geometry"]["coordinates"][1])
        hover_texts.append(eq_dict["properties"]["title"])
    except ValueError:
        print("Data not available.")

# Map the earthquakes.
data = [{
    'type': 'scattergeo',
    'lon': lons,
    'lat': lats,
    'text': hover_texts,

    # Outline marks in the map. 
    'marker': {
        'size': [5*mag for mag in mags],
        'color': mags,
        'colorscale': 'Viridis',
        'reversescale': True,
        'colorbar': {'title': 'Magnitude'},
    },

}]

# One-week Earthquake data output.
my_layout = Layout(title = f'{title}')
fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='sevenday_quakes.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `scattergeo` before, but one quick look at the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scattergeo/#scattergeo-marker-size) reveals:

> size

> Sets the marker size (in px).

> Code:
> fig.update_traces(marker_size=,selector=dict(type='scattergeo'))

> Type: number or array of numbers **greater than or equal to 0**

> Default: 6